# How to get own popup while deletion of application.?

Tags: blackberry

I m creating an application which give me the information of the application which is installed or deleted.
Now i want to get the popup when user click on he delete button from the application manager.
So how can i do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because the deletion of applications is managed by the OS. There is no way to catch the deletion event and load another application which displays a popup.